# Spring Boot Vault HashiCorp - VaultTemplate.read() returns null

Tags: spring, hashicorp-vault

I set the secret like this:

```
vault kv put secret/cats username=tom password=123
```

Configuration of my app:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.vault</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-vault-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

    @Getter
    public class Credentials {
        private String username;
        private String password;
    }

    private VaultTemplate vaultTemplate = new VaultTemplate(VaultEndpoint.from(new URI("http://localhost:8200")),
new TokenAuthentication("s.s2ho5uBRdC5vDODkv6hdMk2C"));

VaultResponseSupport<Credentials> responseSupport = vaultTemplate.
  read("secret/data/cats", Credentials.class);

log.info("username:" + responseSupport.getData().getUsername());
log.info("password:" + responseSupport.getData().getPassword());
```

I check the keys in the vault and they exist there:

```
vault kv get secret/cats
```

But the app returns:

```
username:null
password:null
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late for OP, but I encountered the same issue as a Vault newbie and sharing my solution here.

Most probably the OP was using a [versioned key/value (on Secrets Engine v2)](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/versioned-kv) which is a different format to the original unversioned key values.

**Solution 1: Use `VaultVersionedKeyValueTemplate`**

There is a specific template which supports versioned k/vs.

Construct the template:

```
    private static final String VAULT_PATH_PREFIX = "secret";

    private final VaultVersionedKeyValueTemplate vaultTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public DefaultVaultService(VaultOperations vaultOperations) {
        // VaultVersionedKeyValueTemplate will append "/data" to the prefix
        this.vaultTemplate = new VaultVersionedKeyValueTemplate(vaultOperations, VAULT_PATH_PREFIX);
    }
```

Now fetch the secrets:

```
// get the latest version
Versioned<Credentials> vaultResponse = vaultTemplate.get("/cats", Credentials.class)

// get a specific version
Versioned<Credentials> vaultResponse = vaultTemplate.get("/cats", Versioned.Version.from(2), Credentials.class)
```

**Solution 2: Configure your k/vs as version 1 (unversioned)**
If there is no requirement to maintain versions, just configure your secret as v1 in Vault